# Reduce Section heading number and spacing in document having a table of content

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, sectioning

I have set up a document to have a table of content:

```
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\tableofcontents{}
```

I then have sections within the document which appear in the table of content

```
\section{\small{Introduction}}
```

text

```
\section{\small{Chapter 1}}
```

text

The problem is, at section 1, I get a large 1 followed by the text Introduction which is much smaller. Then in section 2, I get a large 2 followed by the text Chapter 2 which is much smaller. How can I reduce the size of these numbers?

Also the space above and below the section titles is far too large. How can I reduce these?
I tried:

```
 \usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
    \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-5pt}{-5pt}
```

but I still had large spacing above and below the section heading.

Comment: Which document class are you using? Why `\tableofcontents` with an argument?

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{extarticle}

Comment: I added argument: small to table of content  in the hope of making the section number and section spacing smaller

Comment: Do you want to reduce the space between section entries in the ToC or the space between section titles and surrounding text in the document?

Comment: The actual table of content is fine. The problem is the space above and below the section titles is too large. Also the numbers before the section titles are too large.

Comment: Can you give us a complete small document rather than fragments of code? This would be much more useful. Also, are you saying that the space above and below the section titles *in the body of the document* is wrong? Or that the space above and below them *when displayed in the table of contents* is wrong?

Comment: Do you plan to use all sections this way? i.e. `\section{\small some title}`. By the way, please don't use `{\small{text}}` it's `{\small text}`.

Answer (score 1):

The sizes of the sectioning command headings are fixed in the definitions using `\@startsection` -- it's the last argument there.

The spacings before and after the heading can be controlled with the 4th and 5th argument of `\@startsection`.

I changed the values only slightly -- the precise values are left to the O.P -- those values depend on personal preferences, but they shouldn't exceed any boundary, i.e. leak into the margins.

In order to change the size of the ToC entries: `tocloft` and its `\cftsecfont` and `\cftsubsecfont` commands can be redefined to use `\small` or `\tiny`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{extarticle}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-2.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {0.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\small\bfseries}}

\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\tiny\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\tiny}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Foo}
\blindtext
\section{Foobar}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]